# Printing output based on number of times an element occur in list

Tags: python

Currently, i have a list containing:

```
lst = [[2],[2,2],[2,2,2,3,3],[2,3,5,5]]
```

and I'm trying to print out in the format below where:

```
2^1             #since there is only one '2'   
2^2             #since there are two '2' in the first list
2^3 | 3^2       #three '2' and two '3'
2^1 | 3^1 | 5^2 #one '2', one '3' and two '5'
```

I tried:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    count = 1
    if len(lst[i]) == 1:
        print(str(lst[i][0]) + "^" + str(count))
    else:
        for j in range(len(lst[i])-1):
            if lst[i][j] == lst[i][j+1]:
                count+=1
            else:
                print(str(lst[i][j]) + "^" + str(count) + " | " +str(lst[i][j+1]) + "^" +str(count)) 
        if count == len(lst[i]):
            print(str(lst[i][j]) + "^" + str(count))
```

but I'm getting the output of

```
2^1
2^2
2^3 | 3^3
2^1 | 3^1
3^1 | 5^1
```

Would appreciate some help on this

Answer (score 2):

a simple variant using [`itertools.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

for sublist in lst:
    c = Counter(sublist)
    print(' | '.join(f'{number}^{mult}' for number, mult in c.items()))
```

this lets the `Counter` do the work of counting and just displays the items in your desired format.

the `Counter` objects work like dictionaries an look like this (last item in your list):

```
c = Counter({5: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1})
```

as with a `dict` you can iterate over the `key, value` pairs using `c.items()`. the format string `f'{number}^{mult}'` then produces strings like `5^2` which then are [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20join#str.join)ed using the separator `' | '`.

Comment: It would help if you give a small explanation for your code. Anyways, kudos to your answer.

Comment: @Agile_Eagle you are right... was ninja-editing. hope the answer is now +/- self-explanatory (the links to the official doc should make things clear, i hope).

Answer (score 0):

You could use *itertools.groupby* only thing issue is the trailing `|` on the print

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [sorted(i) for i in lst]
for i in lst:
    for k, g in groupby(i):
        print('{}^{} | '.format(k, len(list(g))), end='')
    print()
```

> ```
> 2^1 | 
> 2^2 | 
> 2^3 | 3^2 | 
> 2^1 | 3^1 | 5^2 |
> ```